# wrapper.instance() and wrapper.find(Component).instance() are returning null

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, jestjs, enzyme

consider the below code.

```
    const wrapper = mount(
            <Provider store={store}>
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <ComponentPage/>
                </BrowserRouter>
            </Provider>,
        );
    
    wrapper.instance() // null
    wrapper.find(ComponentPage).instance() //null   ('ComponentPage') or (<ComponentPage/>) //null
    wrapper.children().first().children().first().children().first().instance() //null
```

However `wrapper.name() // Provider` and `wrapper.find(ComponentPage).name() //ComponentPage`

*How to get the instance to test the below code.*

```
test.only('test 1', () => { 
           const app = wrapper.render().find(ComponentPage);
           app.instance().getComponents = jest.fn(); //instance null
           expect(app.instance().getComponents).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [.instance() => ReactComponent](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/instance.html) doc:

> Returns the single-node wrapper's node's underlying class instance; this in its methods. It must be a single-node wrapper.

> NOTE: With React 16 and above, instance() returns null for stateless functional components.

E.g.

`index.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';

export function FunctionComponent() {
  return <div>function component</div>;
}

export class ClassComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>class component</div>;
  }
}
```

`index.test.tsx`:

```
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { ClassComponent, FunctionComponent } from '.';

const store = createStore(() => {});

describe('71204270', () => {
  test('instance is null for function component', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <FunctionComponent />
        </BrowserRouter>
      </Provider>
    );

    console.log(wrapper.find(FunctionComponent).instance());
  });

  test('instance is class instance ', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <ClassComponent />
        </BrowserRouter>
      </Provider>
    );

    console.log(wrapper.find(ClassComponent).instance());
  });
});
```

Test result:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/71204270/index.test.tsx (10.179 s)
  71204270
    ✓ instance is null for function component (49 ms)
    ✓ instance is class instance  (9 ms)

  console.log
    null

      at Object.<anonymous> (stackoverflow/71204270/index.test.tsx:20:13)

  console.log
    <ref *1> ClassComponent {
      props: {},
      context: {},
      refs: {},
      updater: {
        isMounted: [Function: isMounted],
        enqueueSetState: [Function: enqueueSetState],
        enqueueReplaceState: [Function: enqueueReplaceState],
        enqueueForceUpdate: [Function: enqueueForceUpdate]
      },
      _reactInternalFiber: <ref *2> FiberNode {
        tag: 1,
        key: null,
        elementType: [class ClassComponent extends Component],
        type: [class ClassComponent extends Component],
        stateNode: [Circular *1],
        return: FiberNode {
          tag: 10,
          key: null,
          elementType: [Object],
          type: [Object],
          stateNode: null,
          return: [FiberNode],
          child: [Circular *2],
          sibling: null,
          index: 0,
          ref: null,
          pendingProps: [Object],
          memoizedProps: [Object],
          updateQueue: null,
          memoizedState: null,
          dependencies: null,
          mode: 0,
          effectTag: 0,
          nextEffect: null,
          firstEffect: null,
          lastEffect: null,
          expirationTime: 0,
          childExpirationTime: 0,
          alternate: null,
          actualDuration: 0,
          actualStartTime: -1,
          selfBaseDuration: 0,
          treeBaseDuration: 0,
          _debugID: 161,
          _debugIsCurrentlyTiming: false,
          _debugSource: null,
          _debugOwner: [FiberNode],
          _debugNeedsRemount: false,
          _debugHookTypes: null
        },
        child: FiberNode {
          tag: 5,
          key: null,
          elementType: 'div',
          type: 'div',
          stateNode: [HTMLDivElement],
          return: [Circular *2],
          child: null,
          sibling: null,
          index: 0,
          ref: null,
          pendingProps: [Object],
          memoizedProps: [Object],
          updateQueue: null,
          memoizedState: null,
          dependencies: null,
          mode: 0,
          effectTag: 0,
          nextEffect: null,
          firstEffect: null,
          lastEffect: null,
          expirationTime: 0,
          childExpirationTime: 0,
          alternate: null,
          actualDuration: 0,
          actualStartTime: -1,
          selfBaseDuration: 0,
          treeBaseDuration: 0,
          _debugID: 165,
          _debugIsCurrentlyTiming: false,
          _debugSource: null,
          _debugOwner: [Circular *2],
          _debugNeedsRemount: false,
          _debugHookTypes: null
        },
        sibling: null,
        index: 0,
        ref: null,
        pendingProps: {},
        memoizedProps: {},
        updateQueue: {
          baseState: null,
          baseQueue: null,
          shared: [Object],
          effects: null
        },
        memoizedState: null,
        dependencies: null,
        mode: 0,
        effectTag: 1,
        nextEffect: null,
        firstEffect: null,
        lastEffect: null,
        expirationTime: 0,
        childExpirationTime: 0,
        alternate: null,
        actualDuration: 0,
        actualStartTime: -1,
        selfBaseDuration: 0,
        treeBaseDuration: 0,
        _debugID: 163,
        _debugIsCurrentlyTiming: false,
        _debugSource: null,
        _debugOwner: null,
        _debugNeedsRemount: false,
        _debugHookTypes: null
      },
      _reactInternalInstance: {},
      state: null
    }

      at Object.<anonymous> (stackoverflow/71204270/index.test.tsx:32:13)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        10.634 s, estimated 12 s
```

Comment: How to test the methods of a functional component?